# How can I apply a "do nothing" statement for selection of elements in a matrix within matlab?

Tags: matlab

The code below (which is part of a larger code) finds the element with the maximum value within a 'range' of 10 elements from a starting position (xpos, ypos) in matrix A. Completing this action is dependent on whether a certain probability (prob_thermoreg) is greater than a random number (rn). This is done for 120 iterations. The problem that I am running into is the following: Say (for simplicity, and so that I won't have to put up the rest of the code) 'prob_thermoreg' is greater than 'rn' always, and the for the first iteration, the element with the highest value within the 'range' is selected. For the second iteration, no other element can be selected because the element with the maximum value was already selected in the first iteration, so it's "stuck". Subsequently, I receive an error.

I'm assuming I would need an if statement before the last "end" that will circumvent the errors that I'm getting. I just want the same element that is already selected, to be selected again the next iteration. I'm not sure if this is equivalent to a "do nothing" statement in other languages. Any help is appreciated!

```
maxtime=120
    for i=1:maxtime
    xstart=xpos-range
    ystart=ypos-range

       if prob_thermoreg>rn;
          % The logic below will find the element with the highest value from    the starting positions, xpos, ypos.
           maxtreecover = 0.0;  %find value larger than this
           maxx_tree = xstart;
           maxy_tree = ystart;

        for jj=1:20 
            for ii=1:20

                if A(ystart + ii,xstart + jj) > maxtreecover; % if the value of A at different ii and jj is greater than maxtreecover
                 maxtreecover = A(ystart + ii,xstart + jj); %the element with the highest value is selected
                 maxx_tree = xstart + jj;
                 maxy_tree = ystart + ii;       
            end
        end 
       end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri, I think I made the necessary corrections. Also, I don't have a while statement, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, got it, thanks. I'll work on properly indenting this.

Comment: This should be properly indented now.

Comment: Also, cosnider adding a fully runnable [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it

```
xstart = xpos - range;
ystart = ypos - range;
% Find the subset of A that spans the range around the start positions
A_in_range = A(ystart:(ystart+2*range), xstart:(xstart+2*range))
% Find the maximum value and its position in this subset. I have converted 
% the matrix into a column vector to find max over all values. This will 
% give the max value and the index in the column vector
[maxtreecover, max_ind] = max(A_in_range(:))
% Convert the vector index to a matrix index
[max_ypos, max_xpos] = ind2sub([2*range+1, 2*range+1], max_ind)
% Find the actual index in your original A matrix
maxy_tree = xstart + max_xpos - 1
maxx_tree = ystart + max_ypos - 1
```

Comment: Thank you @ammportal, this will repeat 120 times. Will this work, for example, if the maximum within the range is selected in iteration 1, and can selected again the next iteration?

Comment: yes, it should be able to select the maximum around any range in each iteration. However, it will only report the first maximum that it finds.